# Unexpected token ILLEGAL on .click()

Tags: jquery

Been trying to find what's wrong with my code here:

```
<p class="text text-2">Name:</p>
    <input class="_input-1" type="text" id="usernameCs">
    <p class="text text-4">Email:</p>
    <input class="_input-2" type="text">
    <p class="text text-6">Phone:</p>
    <input class="_input-5" type="text">
    <button id ="sendAuth" onclick="javascript:void(0);">SEND</button>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(#sendAuth).click(function(){
    var csUsername = $("#usernameCs").val();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://warwick.a2retail.com',
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      data: {
        transactionType: 'basic_user_information_login',
        requesterName: 'Project Eden',
        serviceProviderId: 'rlp-99b3c3df-9e25-4503-bbb9-a92126d6afb6',
        userId: 'csUsername',
        payload: {}
      }
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Essentially, I'm trying to make an ajax POST request, but couldn't get my head around the error that I got. I got error on the `$(#sendAuth).click(function(){` line. I have referenced jQuery correctly in the head.

Comment: You missed a comma after `data`.

Comment: It should be `$("#sendAuth")`, You need to pass selector in quotes. Voting to close as typo

Comment: Is it that you are missing a `,` before the `success` of AJAX?

Comment: Please read a jQuery tutorial: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert this

```
$(#sendAuth)
```

to this

```
$("#sendAuth")
```

Add comma after data

like this

```
data: {
    transactionType: 'basic_user_information_login',
    requesterName: 'Project Eden',
    serviceProviderId: 'rlp-99b3c3df-9e25-4503-bbb9-a92126d6afb6',
    userId: 'csUsername',
    payload: {}
}, success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}
```